# Решите задачу по множествам

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Напишите функцию, принимающую числовое множество и
возвращающую количество содержащихся в нём элементов. 
Ниже я пытался решить. Откорректируйте решение, потому что это не работает.

```
function go(arg: set of integer): byte;
var
  m: integer;
  i: integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  for m := 0 to 255 do
    if not (arg[m] = []) then i := i + 1;{ТУТ ОН ПИШЕТ ОШИБКУ:Нет индексного свойства по умолчанию для типа set of integer}
  result := i;
end;

var
  s: set of integer;
  c: string;

begin
  s := [1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
  writeln(go(s))
end.
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нет индексного свойства по умолчанию для типа set of integer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1025953/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-set-of-integer)

Comment: Нет, там на другую тему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для проверки принадлежности элемента множества используется оператор `IN`. Т.е. ваш код для классического паскаля будет иметь такой вид

```
for m := 0 to 255 do begin
  if m in arg then
    i := i + 1;
end;
```

Число 255 взято, т.к. в паскале элементами множества могут быть только числа от 0 до 255 или элементы перечислимого типа.

В PascalABC.net элемента множества могут быть любыми, но в PascalABC.net (как и последние версии Delphi) есть цикл `for in`, который позволяет просто перебрать все элементы множества. С этим циклом код сократится до двух строчек

```
for m in arg do
  i := i + 1;
```

Comment: Но тогда элемент массива не сможет быть больше 255

Comment: @Влад Обновил ответ